# How to slice characters from string using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the string `AccountDB\\DB`.

I want to remove the 4 characters in the end `\\DB`, so desired result is a string looks like `AccountDB`.

How can I slice the last four characters using regex?

Comment: The point is you *wouldn't* use regex for this when you could just do indexOf.  Is there a particular reason why you would want to use regular expressions?

Comment: The length of everything before and after `\\\` is always identical? if yes, then using regex isn't a good approach. But it it is dynamic, then regex could be fine.

Comment: @Shafizadeh nah, get the index of the first instance of `\\`, then substring from the start of the string to the index discovered first. Regex is just overkill for this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First `\\` will be converted to `\` in javascript since the backslash sign `\` is used to escape the next character, so your string will look like :

```
"AccountDB\DB"
```

You could remove the three characters at the end without regex just using `slice()` function :

```
"AccountDB\\DB".slice(0, -3); //return AccountDB
```

```js
alert("AccountDB\\DB".slice(0, -3));
```

---

If you need really to use regex you could use :

```
/(.+)(...)$/
```

- **`.`** : Matches any character (except newline).
- **`+`** : Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible
- **`(...)$`** : Any three characters at end of the string

Hope this helps.

---

```js
alert("AccountDB\\DB".match(/(.+)(...)$/)[1]);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try using [str.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to extract the a sub string.

```
var re = /(.*?)\\\\\S+/
var string1 = "AccountDB\\\\DB"

var newstr = string1.replace(re, "$1")
console.log(newstr)
```

Output:

```
AccountDB
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use replace. For instance:-

```
var myString = "A (complete garbage) string";
var result = myString.replace(/\s\([\w\s\.]+\)/gi, ''); //result is "A string"
```

In your case it would be:-

```
alert(("AccountDB\\DB").replace(\\.*$/g, ''));
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

REGEX solution:

```
^([a-zA-Z]*)\\
```

And `$1` is containing what you want.

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vV4qR0/2)

```js
var str = 'AccountDB\\DB';
var result = /^([a-zA-Z]*)\\/.exec(str);
document.write(result[1])
```